# How do I know if an Apple Pencil 2 is original/authentic or fake?

Tags: apple-pencil

A friend of mine gifted me an Apple Pencil 2 a few days ago. When I pasted its serial number to Apple's coverage site, it **does** say that it is indeed an Apple Pencil 2, **but** it displays the message "Sorry, we’re currently unable to validate your purchase date".

[image: Screenshot of Apple's Support site showing an error message about not being able to validate the purchase date]

Does this message tell something about the originality of the Pencil? Or is it conclusive enough already that it is original as it displays that the device is Apple Pencil 2? Well, I am only concerned on knowing if the Pencil is indeed original/authentic, that's all

Answer (score 1):

#### Your device is authentic

*The purchase date isn't what authenticates it as genuine; the fact that the serial number is recognized does.*

The purchase date only validates warranty eligibility (AppleCare).  There could be an error within the purchase transaction record, the device could have been a promotional unit, it could have been originally acquired via a "five finger discount," or any other number of scenarios.

#### Purchase date is related to AppleCare

The error message can also be read as "Sorry, we can't tell you if the device is covered under warranty."  If I put in a SN# of a product with a valid purchase date, AppleCare (warranty) info is populated.

[image]

You have a genuine Pencil, but the only issue you'd have is not being able to return it under warranty coverage; probably moot by now as the standard warranty is 1 year in the US and 2 in Europe.